# Unable to connect from BigQuery job to Cloud SQL Postgres in different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am not able to add an external connexion in BigQuery (in project A), to a Cloud SQL Postgres (in project B).

I want to use EXTERNAL_QUERY statement but I am not able to connect to my Cloud SQL instance.

The error when I want to add a connection is as follows:

CloudSQL instances must be in the same project as the query connection. CloudSQL instance project: B, connection project: A

Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#limitations):

> **Project**. You **must** create the connection resource **in the same project** as the Cloud SQL instance.

The only way is to create BigQuery EXTERNAL_QUERY in the project B and use it from your project A.